# Why does training a pretrained model take longer time?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

From my limited experience in training and testing object detection models like faster rcnn I've noticed that whenever I set the variable pretrained to True the training time took way more than when I trained it with pretrained set to False. The model that I've particularly seen this effect on is Faster RCNN with ResNet50 fpn backbone that has pretrained weights from ImageNet dataset.

I've googled the sentence "Why does training a pretrained model take longer time?" and all it shows is examples of "How to use pretrained model...etc." and not "Why.." 
So I felt curious to know if anyone here could explain or hint.

Comment: Do you mean that it takes longer to converge or that each iteration is slower?

Comment: Iteration is slower. Each epoch takes more time. @hkchengrex